# What am i doing wrong? And what should i be doing differently? (Auto complete winforms textbox)

Tags: c#, winforms

c# winform

I have read multiple articles/suggestions on how to do this, and below is one of the few I have tried, but it's not working.  In fact, when user types into the textbox, nothing happens.

```
private void OperationListForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AutoCompleteStringCollection textBoxCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        foreach (var item in _oiList)  //_oiList is a list of objects 
        {
            textBoxCollection.Add(item.ToString());
        }

        textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = textBoxCollection;
    }
```

I'm new so, If I need to provide more info, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things you need to double check:

- Make sure that textBoxCollection has valid items in it
- Make sure that your 'OperationListForm_Load' method is being called by setting a breakpoint and running your application
- Make sure your textBox1 is added to the form properly

I tested your code and it works for me. This is what I did to check:

1. Created a new Windows Form project
2. Added a Text Box to the form
3. Added the following code to the Form1.cs:

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
     public Form1()
     {
       InitializeComponent();
       InitTextBox();
     }

     void InitTextBox()
     {
        AutoCompleteStringCollection textBoxCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        textBoxCollection.Add("Bobby");
        textBoxCollection.Add("Billy");
        textBoxCollection.Add("Britney");

        textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = textBoxCollection;
     }
   }
   ```

and here is a screenshot of this working:

[image: screenshot of working code]

Comment: Make sure that textBoxCollection has valid items in it ... emphasis on VALID items.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First you must create array and add it to `AutoCompleteStringCollection`, next set it as data source. You can do it like my sample, its working. Your problem is with your `datasource` which you try add. It's list of object you cant do that.

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection stringCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
String[] yourArray = new[] {"Cat", "Car", "Dog", "Dinner", "War", "White"};
stringCollection.AddRange(yourArray);
textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = stringCollection;
textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

[image]

Comment: You're right; it is a list of objects.  But since, in the foreach , I add the "item.ToString()" to the textBoxCollection, shouldn't the textBoxCollection still contain a list of strings (instead of objects) ?